# I am confused on how to approach the Fourier series of a piecewise function. Here's an example of such a function:

Tags: fourier-analysis, fourier-series, fourier-transform

Here is the function:
$$
f(x) = \begin{cases}
  0, & 0 < x < 1, \\
  1, & 1 < x < 2, \\
  0, & 2 < x < 3.
\end{cases}
$$

Can someone help explain this to me?

Comment: For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [here](/help/notation), [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [here](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [here](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I formatted your function how I think you want it done.